# Python - Problems passing value into Dataframe

Tags: python, twitter, pandas

I'm trying to access the 'country' value in a json I got from twitter. I used the straming API to get some tweets and saved them into a file.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tweets_data_path = 'E:/Python_prog/twitter_data.json'
tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")

for line in tweets_file:
    try:

        tweets_data.append(json.loads(line))

    except:
        pass
```

That' how I access my data.

Passing 'text' and 'lang' into the Dataframe is no problem.

```
tweets = pd.DataFrame()

tweets['text'] = [tweet['text'] for tweet in tweets_data]
tweets['lang'] = [tweet['lang'] for tweet in tweets_data]
```

I know that 'place' can be empty so I tried this:

```
for tweet in tweets_data:
    if tweet['place'] is not None:
        print(tweet['place']['country'])
        tweets['country'] = tweet['place']['country']
```

I used print to check if I got the correct value and that works.
I get this output:

```
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
Malaysia
United States
United States
United States
United States
```

but it does not pass into the tweets['country'] Dataframe.
I'm checking the Dataframe after with

> print(tweets['country'])

and thats my output:

```
0      United States
1      United States
2      United States
3      United States
4      United States
5      United States
6      United States
7      United States
8      United States
9      United States
.. 
302    United States
303    United States
```

I think it goes to 303 because there are  304 tweets in my file.
My problem is passing the the value correctly into the Dataframe but not sure how.
I'm using these Dataframes to make tables with matplotlib later.

**edit:**
as requested a sample of the json file I use:
**edit2:**
deleted the sample of the json since I got an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Please add some samples of the .json file you're working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue basically occurs because you are assigning to your dataframe like -

```
tweets['country'] = tweet['place']['country']
```

You are trying to assign a single value to the whole series , so it completely overwrites all the values with that value. Example -

```
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]],columns = ['A','B'])

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4

In [5]: df['C'] = 2

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   A  B  C
0  1  2  2
1  3  4  2
```

I would suggest you create your DataFrame as -

```
tweet_list = [[tweet['text'], tweet['lang'], tweet.get('place','<some default dict with country key>')['country']] for tweet in tweets_data]

tweets = pd.DataFrame(tweet_list, columns=['text','lang','country'])
```

You would need to provide some default value for tweets that don't have country,you can provide an empty string there. `dict.get(key)` ,without second argument by default returns None, if key is not found.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can provide a default value for tweets that don´t have a country. Could you tell me how?

Comment: Create a dictionary with the default value assigned to the country key , and use that as the second argument of the .get() call .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `tweets['country'] = tweet['place']['country']` reassigns the entire column each time (You get the result you do because the last country in your loop is 'United States'.)

Besides, you have not specified what you wanted to do when 'country' is None.

How about:

```
tweets['country'] = [tweet['place']['country'] for tweet in tweets_data]
tweets['country'].fillna('N/A', inplace=True)
```